# How to show text below image on small viewport?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display each image and its description on each half of the current browser screen. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
         <a href="#"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
         <p>Here is the description</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I resize and reach the mobile phone viewport, the image and text are still displaying on each half of the screen. How can I make them display on top of each other, i.e: the text should be displayed right below the image on the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col-6` split the screen for every viewport. You should use `col-sm`, `col-md`, `col-lg` or `col-xl`, depending on which screen size you wish to add the grid breakpoint.

You can check more informations here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Just a note for readers, `col-xs-*` only applies to Bootstrap versions <4.x after that it's deprecated.

Comment: @ChrisW. yes, my mistake. `col-xs` is indeed deprecated, but `col-sm` is still working. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, so i'm using `col-6-md` now. What happens is that at a full desktop viewport, it still splits the row into 2. What I'm trying to achieve is that it should only split when viewing on mobile, and should not split when viewing on desktop. how can i fix it?

Comment: @Kiddo actually is `col-md-6`, not `col-6-md`... could you try the correct one, please?

Comment: apologies my typo, i'm using `col-md-6`, still the `<div class="row">` split into 2 when viewing on desktop

Comment: If you have imported Bootstrap correctly, and if you are viewing it on a device with more than 768px width, it shoud have worked correctly. And just checking, you have removed the `col-6`, correct? Just use `col-md-6`...

Comment: thanks for your reply, i was using an older version of boostrap, changing it to the latest one fix the issue (not sure why).

Answer (score 0):

You're using bootstrap, so just use the baked in [responsive utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#responsive-classes);

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
         <a href="#"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
         <p>Here is the description</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these breakpoints for mobile devices
@media(max-width:600px) //for mobile devices
@media(min-width:600px) //for laptop screens

Then use grid property
refer: [Grid property](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)